# Why does British Humanist Association advocate for abortion rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, abortion, humanism

When going over the website of the [Humanists.UK](https://humanists.uk/what-you-can-do-to-help/protect-legal-abortions/) I discovered that this organization advocates for extended abortion rights.

This looks to me highly counterintuitive. I was always convinced that a human is the central value of humanism. Logically following, killing a human should be among the worst things that another human could possibly do, so I expected them to advocate against it, unless maybe for some very extreme cases.

Comment: Maybe the Humanists.UK explained it? Especially it would probably depend on the definition of a human (especially the begin). I could imagine that not all people in the world have the same ideas there. Your premise might be flawed. Do these Humanists explain what they consider human life?

Comment: At least in the linked page, there is no clear explanation, this is taken as something obvious while for me it is not. As much as I understand E.Kant and his categorical imperative, who needs life and freedom self, should not take from another.

Comment: Why to close? The answer looks good and explains me.

Comment: Not me, but people might wonder what the connection to politics is. Humanists.UK is just a private club publishing their own private opinions. This site's purpose is not to explain everything.

Comment: First, BHA are *secular* humanists. Second, they explain their position on abortion [rather extensively](https://understandinghumanism.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Abortion-humanist-perspective.pdf). So this does feel like a low effort Q. (But I haven't DV it myself.)

Comment: While I agree with Fizz about the lack of research, I voted to reopen since abortion rights represent a rather hot political topic nowadays.

Comment: Humanism is a philosophy or arguably a religion, not a political movement. This is off-topic. If you want to know how humanism relates to abortion, ask on Philosophy SE.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The abortion debate is not about whether or not it is morally acceptable to "kill a human". That's actually a point where pro-life and pro-choice organizations pretty much agree. The actual question where they disagree on is "when exactly does human life begin?".

At birth? At viability out of the uterus? At measurable brain function? At heartbeat? At conception? At ovulation and ejaculation? At meiosis? And unfortunately there is no obvious and objective way to answer this. It is mostly a philosophical question. Which is why it is so difficult to come to a consensus on the matter.

Pro-life proponents tend to put this bar a lot lower, while pro-choice proponents like the here mentioned Humanists UK put it a lot higher. And as humanists they do not see why an entity that they do not consider to be human life should have more rights than a fully-grown human being.

Another aspect to abortion that is relevant to the humanist perspective is that of bodily autonomy. Humanists believe that everyone has the right to bodily autonomy. Which means that interfering with the body of a person requires their consent. So even if you assume that the object in the uterus fulfills the definition of a human person, then there is still the question if this person has the right to make use of another person's body to ensure their survival without the consent of that person (and no, there is no right or wrong answer to this question either, so please no debate in the comments).

Comment: The explanation you gave me first looks much more convincible.

Comment: @Stančikas Well, the purpose of this question is to tell you what the humanist perspective on abortion *is*, not to convince you that any particular argument that results from it is convincing or that any particular opinion on the matter is the correct one. That's something we should leave to an online community that is dedicated to promoting humanism.

Comment: I see you deleted the comments. Can you at least edit the first 2 sentences, because those are currently objectively and demonstrably false. In addition to whether a fetus should be considered to be a human, there is much debate about whether an unwelcome pregnancy would serve as moral justification to "kill a human" (comparable to how you're morally justified in killing someone to defend yourself). You also alluded to this by mentioning bodily autonomy. This is far from a point of agreement between pro-choice and anti-abortion.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: The distinction that this answer makes is that in discussing "killing a human is immoral", the focus is not on any disagreement that killing a human is immoral (both sides agree there), but rather than if the object in question were not considered to be a human (which is the pro-choice stance), it would render the immorality of killing a human to be moot given that the object in question is not considered a human to begin with. This answer correctly points out that distinction in its first part.

Comment: @NotThatGuy _"You also alluded to this by mentioning bodily autonomy."_ And thus we get to the second part of the answer - which is independent of the first part. It seems like you missed that this answer consists of two independent arguments. The latter part is not a continuation of the former part; these are two _separate_ arguments that are both being used as a way to express how a humanist can come to the conclusion that abortion is justifiable without conflicting with the notion of humanism itself: (a) because a fetus is not human or (b) because a pregnant person retains bodily autonomy.

Answer (score 38):

I'm always fascinated when I have to point this out, but... Women are human too. They have the same rights and liberties as any other human, Even if we ascribe full rights to fetuses — a philosophically debatable point — women would *still* have the same rights. That means that the legal question here is this: whose rights predominate when human rights come into conflict? I assume the Humanist logic is that we cannot blithely and smugly discard the rights of women in all cases.

Remember, one doesn't have to be in favor of the *act of abortion* to support *abortion rights*. Sometimes unpleasant acts are necessary to preserve the system of rights as a whole.

Most places in the world legally excuse killing in given contexts: defending one's life or welfare, or the life or welfare of others; protecting homes and certain kinds of property; public executions for high crimes; death during police or military activity; even (at certain times and places) combat over insults to honor or pride. In all those cases the legal argument is that the killer had the *right* to deprive the victim of life. This was the essence of Roe, that a woman has a right to privacy (aka, freedom from government interference) that trumps any rights a fetus might have, at least for the first trimester. Removing that right explicitly reduces women to chattel — property 'owned' by the fetus - which is inconsistent with the rights and liberties afforded humans in liberal society.

Comment: I think it's unfair to suggest people are "blithely and smugly" discarding the rights of women.  From what I've seen many of the people opposed to abortion are women (and of course many pro-abortionists are women too).  People "just" have different priorities.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine: Well, we can debate the adjectives if you like, but the clear fact is that pro-life political actors routinely refuse to talk about women as people with intrinsic rights. I suspect that's intentional, because they know as well as I do that any recognition of women's rights automatically legitimizes abortion in certain cases and undercuts the hard-line argument they want to make. If you don't like 'blithely' or 'smugly' we could try others. I'd lean towards 'maliciously' or 'peremptorily', but you might prefer 'studiously' or 'systematically'. Let me know.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine There are women who explicitly argue that women should obey the wishes of their husbands, so it is certainly possible to be a woman and simultaneously discard the rights of women in general.

Comment: Unfortunately this issue has always tended to cause people to pick one extreme or another.  "Abortion" has, in medical terms, a lot of room for compromise, it's just a shame that people don't seem to want to find a compromise.  Certainly there are factions in both camps that won't tolerate any compromise and they're the problem, not the solution.  I believe the majority from both viewpoints could find a middle ground, but not while the extremists in both camps are the ones driving things.  Politics is about compromise, that's it's purpose.  I don't think your choice of language helps.

Comment: I'll simply say one more thing : it is my personal belief that men should never be allowed vote on abortion.  We don't have to carry the baby in our bodies, we don't have to risk our lives in childbirth and, sadly, some men don't even regard bringing up a child as their responsibility.  I've never felt we should have men voting on this because we don't suffer the consequences like women do.  Men can express an opinion but I think we should leave it at that.

Comment: This is my favorite answer here and reminds me of [Judith Jarvis Thomson: A Defense of Abortion](https://spot.colorado.edu/~heathwoo/Phil160,Fall02/thomson.htm)

Comment: @StephenG Late stage abortions have already practically only been happening in medically necessary cases. Pro-choice can and do compromise to some degree, because the idea of having some time to make up your mind, and then having the decision be final, is already the case given the fact that you'll give birth eventually. Anti-abortion can't reasonably compromise, and few make compromises beyond rape and incest, if they even allow that: the issue is that if you believe the rights of a fetus can outweigh the rights of a woman, that's rather binary. But the majority of people are pro-choice.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Consider it from the pro-life perspective; each abortion is a murder.  How can you compromise with that and live with yourself.  "Some murder is ok" is essentially what an abortion compromise looks like to a pro-life person.

Comment: Fun fact: The period in the life of a woman when she has the most rights is when she's a fetus.

Comment: @Ryan_L: Please use the right terminology. From the pro-life perspective abortion is **homicide** — death derived from human action — but not every homicide is murder. If a woman shoots an assailant, if a man shoots a trespasser, if a police officer shoots a suspect: none of these homicides are murder, not unless the person is charged and convicted in court. The bible (not to mention history) is full of people killing other people for the glory of God, and none of that is considered 'murder'. Killing a fetus is no different if there's a legal justification for it.

Comment: Can you give an example of a murderer who has been set free because the victim has caused him discomfort? (even extreme physical pain)

Comment: @Jacob3: Do you think pregnancy is merely a 'discomfort', like eating too much greasy food or something? You might want to ask your mother about that...

Comment: @TedWrigley, Unless if one of us is an alien; For the most part, yes. And if requested most doctors would allow epidural, upon request.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine You can't always have compromise. That general policy leads to [the tyranny of the least compromising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_tolerance): if you compromise and others don't, do you compromise again? And again?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You've presented an argument for never compromising.  That's not how politics is done.  The problem with many nations now, especially the US, is that extremist positions are being taken and compromise is refused as one or both sides (on any issue, not just abortion) will not budge because they consider any movement as defeat.  Again I say, that's not politics, it's extremism.  If you cannot let yourself compromise, you can never reach a middle ground, even if it's just an inch away.  People need to stop listening to extremist positions.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I've presented an argument for never _unilaterally_ compromising, which is what seemed to have been described in your comment. One party compromising is not consensus: it's the will of one party being arbitrarily privileged over another's, with a side-order of guilt-tripping. (This is common in abusive relationships, hence why I'm bringing it up; it's not the sort of argument I want to see legitimised.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Perhaps you should look up the word "compromise" is a dictionary.  While it's certainly possible to make a compromise where one side gives something and another does not, I don't know how you read that as my primary intention when all I've said is "compromise".  I sometimes describe a compromise as an agreement reached to allow both sides to get something, while making none of them happy in private, but allowing both to claim a face-saving victory in public.  Politics, in other words.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine I can see a reading of your comment where you weren't saying what I thought you were; though I'm not sure how applicable that reading is to the real-world political situation. In practice, we have a multimodal distribution: people with varying attitudes towards the validity of abortion in the it-should-be-legal camp, then a spike of "no, never" in the (minority) it-should-be-a-crime camp. Uncompromising extremists are not, to my knowledge, “driving things” in the pro-choice movement.

Comment: @StephenG There is certainly a problem with people refusing to "live and let live" (which is hardly even a compromise). But the bigger problem I see with the US at the moment is that the 2-party system is making it shift further and further from democracy, and those in charge are enacting more extreme legislation that the majority of people disagree with (like abolishing Roe v Wade). Never mind that half the population is quite far detached from reality given the constant stream of lies they've been fed (and which side this is will obviously depend on which side you ask).

Comment: @Jacob3 Pregnancy is uncomfortable/painful and dangerous to a woman's health and life through the whole pregnancy, not just during the actual birth! ...and considering drug-addicts have been imprisoned for using drugs during pregnancy...

Comment: @BaardKopperud: Not to mention financial costs for prenatal care, loss of income and career opportunities, the high cost and forced labor of raising a child. Not a problem if a woman *chooses* to subject herself to those costs and restrictions; quite a problem if a woman is *forced* to pay those costs and restrictions by the state.

Answer (score 11):

To answer this Q narrowly, the BHA [explains](https://understandinghumanism.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Abortion-humanist-perspective.pdf) their position through the voice of British (humanist) philosopher Richard Norman:

> It is sometimes
> suggested that a key question for the abortion
> debate is ‘When does life begin?’, and that
> differing views on abortion derive from different
> answers to that question. For humanists, this is
> the wrong question. The appropriate question is:
> ‘When does a life begin?’. The natural and
> obvious answer is that a person’s life begins
> when they are born. That is what we mean by
> ‘birth’. Only then does a living human being start
> interacting with the world, experiencing and
> responding to the world and to other people. An
> abortion is not an act of ending a person’s life,
> or depriving them of their life, because there is
> not yet a person who is living a life. The word
> ‘potential’ is often used to describe the status of
> a foetus, and humanists would say that that
> word gets it right. A foetus is a potential person
> with the potentiality for having a life. That is
> why a decision whether or not to have an
> abortion is a serious decision. But it is not a
> decision whether to kill someone.

Aside, as for its US counterpart "The AHA was the first national membership organization to support abortion rights." (--Wikipedia)

It is true however that the wider/broader [Amsterdam Declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Declaration) (signed by BHA, AHA, but also other groups) isn't taking an explicit stance on abortion, but it still is a secular declaration, by and large, presenting itself as "an alternative to dogmatic religion" among other things. But back in the 1970s, when the [IHEU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanists_International) had a much more Malthusian [world]view of the future, their board of directors [did](https://humanists.international/policy/population-control-family-planning-and-abortion/) propose that

> medical abortion should be available to women on request as a fundamental human right and as an additional means of population control.

Comment: The only answer, at present, which conforms with the site guidelines by using the group itself as a source for its own motivations, rather than engaging in speculation.

Comment: An important section of the BHA article that's probably also worth quoting: "Typically, wherever humanists lie on the question of when an abortion would be morally acceptable, they will defend a woman’s right to choose. Primarily because, for the woman, it is a choice over whether or not another potential human being should have the use of her body. ... in the case of abortion, many humanists believe that the woman’s right to make decisions over the use of her own body are strong enough to allow her allow the right to an abortion if that is what she wishes"

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend further reading on "[Humanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanism#Etymology_and_definition)" on Wikipedia.

Based on what I can gather, humanism is not all that concerned with abortion.

While the ideology is concerned with morality, it is more interested in the **process** of how morality is formed, rather than an **outcome** of what morality should look like.

---

Humanism is a belief that individual humans have power to shape their own world, and therefore also carry the responsibility to exercise those powers appropriately.

This ideology probably comes in a time when the prevailing worldview argues something different, which is that humans have no agency and should defer decision-making to a higher power - namely God.

Humanists believe that:

- Humans have agency and should actively form their own values instead of deferring morality to other sources, such as God.
- Humans should engage in scientific inquiry because you cannot exercise agency without being informed.
- Humans should pursue a self-defined, meaningful, and happy life.
- Humans should follow a set of morality that aligns with human flourishing.
- Humans should engage in practical actions that improve personal and social conditions.

From this, we can derive that humanism is probably also complementary with secularism, democracy, and pluralism.

We can probably also say that the modern world is a predominantly humanist world. Most of us, without realizing it, are already humanists.

---

To answer your questions on abortion.

I think humanism is muted on this subject. It does not take sides with regards to whether abortion is moral.

What I can say is that humanism seems to encourage democratic deliberation on this subject, and for different societies to reach different conclusions on whether to allow abortion, and if so, the extent to which the practice should be allowed (i.e. at different stages of trimester).

Inversely, humanism would probably discourage an authoritarian approach to controlling people's reproductive ability (e.g. [Romania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decree_770), [China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-child_policy)), or to defer the question of abortion to God or some external source separate from mortal humans.

Comment: Points 3, 4 and 5 all seem to be pro-choice.

Comment: @user253751 I stand corrected, I read your first comment as "pro-life" when you meant "pro-choice". You are correct that point 3-5 are not necesssarily against abortion, it depends entirely on the legal context.

Comment: I presume you largely quoted Andrew Copson with your list of humanist beliefs (given that it's almost word-for-word the same as what's written on Wikipedia - a citation for that is probably in order, to avoid plagiarism), but you changed a key detail: you said humans "should" pursue a happy life, whereas Andrew said humanists "place importance" on the pursuit of a happy life. The crucial difference is that placing importance on something applies to other people too: I can find your pursuit of a happy life to be important.

Comment: *In your opinion*, humanism is mute on this subject. In the opinion of most people who call themselves humanists, bodily autonomy is a basic human right and is a core part of humanist ideals (a lack of bodily autonomy makes it much harder to live a self-defined life, and to find meaning and happiness). Pro-choice preserves that right, and anti-abortion disregards it, and being democratically agreed upon most definitely doesn't make it okay to disregards it. (Of course most humanists support democracy, so they would try to convince people in a democracy.)

Comment: @NotThatGuy The difference between "should" and "places importance" seems interchangeable for me in this context. The keyword is "happiness" which is a radical departure from other theories in past periods. If you were a Russian serf in the 1500s, the idea that your happiness was more important than what God wanted would be nothing short of heresey. Like I said, the modern world is predominantly humanist, we live it like fish in water, it's so omipresent that we barely recognize it.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I don't disagree that democracy tend to facilitate pro-choice positions, which absolutely bears out in reality. But since human rights depend on rule of law, and rule of law depends on democracy, and democracy depends on continous deliberation, it necessarily means you have to recognize the possibility that a country's voters could - in theory - reverse those rights (e.g. Nazi Germany). I say humanism is muted on abortion because, while there is a storng correlation between democracy and human rights, there is always an inherent possibility that the former can undo the later.

Comment: I find a bit biased how you mention Romania and China but not the USA. Probably because of the previous mention of "authoritarian vs democratic government", but I would turn the point on its head and wonder how democratic is a country that deprives you of such basic rights. That would be opening a can of worms, though, and I have no energy to pick them up afterwards

Comment: @QuantumWalnut I explained the difference between "should" and "places importance", it doesn't add much to say they seem interchangeable. If you "should" pursue a happy life, that suggests more of a "live and let live position": you'd only stop people trying to interfere with your own ability to live a happy life. But if you "place importance" on a happy life, it would make sense to try to stop anyone interfering with anyone else's ability to live a happy life (i.e. a humanist who isn't capable of giving birth could fight for abortion rights).

Comment: @QuantumWalnut Humanists typically support democracy and human rights (including the right to bodily autonomy), but just because the former can undo the latter, that doesn't mean it's "muted" on human rights (at least not by any reasonable definition of "muted" that I can see). You can think that the best way to rule is through majority vote, while also having opinions about how to best rule, and expressing these opinions to others to try to influence the majority vote (which is *also* an important part of a health democracy). Those things aren't in conflict with one another.

Answer (score 8):

Philipp explained how humanism is not fundamentally *inconsistent* with a philosophical stance supporting abortion rights. But humanism is likewise not "obviously" inconsistent with a philosophical stance rejecting abortion rights, so it still bears asking why that particular organization has affirmed that particular stance.

As a social movement made up of like-minded individuals, humanism is strongly associated with social liberalism, due to its basic opposition to religious orthodoxy being a basis of social standards and government. Ultimately, if your cluster of beliefs is such that you tend to agree with humanists, it probably *also* includes support for abortion rights, simply based on how you were raised, what news sources you read, and who your friends are. And since humanism is ultimately a *moral philosophy*, a humanist organization is going to feel obliged to take a stance on it.

One could readily imagine a humanist organization convincingly (or at least convincingly self-consistently) advocating for abortion restrictions. But it would be difficult to imagine where such an organization would find its members.

Comment: I'd like to think that support for human rights is based on something other than the birth lottery.

Comment: @user253751 You would have a real hard time arguing that one's moral philosophy is not in part a product of their environment. There's many millennia of evidence to contend with.

Comment: oh it is, objectively, but it's a very narrow view that misses the point, like saying the reason that I have a certain genetic code, say "endothelin receptor type B", because both my parents had it, rather than saying evolution chose it because it's a good endothelin receptor for humans because of the temperature or acidity or whatever.

Comment: @user253751 If you believe that Humanism UK's position on abortion is the inevitable result of their fundamental philosophy, you should add that as an answer. I don't think there's anything in your comments I can use to improve this answer.

Comment: One could similarly argue that an inability to see the "obvious" inconsistency between humanism and anti-abortion is because anti-abortion is strongly associated with conservatism, which opposes "liberal" ideals due to their disagreement on many issues, and religion, which disregards moral concerns that may conflict with one's religious beliefs. But these types of arguments tend to not lead anywhere, other than to make you feel better about others disagreeing with you, and to harm constructive discourse by implying others won't otherwise be convinced by the arguments they use.

Answer (score 1):

Abortion only kills a foetus in the way that switching off life support in a hospital kills a human.  Even if a foetus is a person, the continued survival of that person relies on the life support provided by the mother.  The actual cause of death is not the abortion, but that the foetus cannot survive outside the womb (a very late pregnancy can be terminated/aborted without the death of the baby, a topic I rarely see addressed in abortion debates).

The question then becomes if it is morally right to force one person to provide life support for another person.  Suppose that Carmen has a twin sister who can *only* survive if Carmen donates her kidney, and will definitely die otherwise.  Many people would argue that, if it is safe for Carmen to do so, it would be morally right for her to donate her kidney.  But very few people would argue that the law could force Carmen to do so, because forcing this goes against Carmens bodily autonomy.

Forcing a person to provide medical life support to another person — whether the other person is a foetus in her womb or a twin sister needing an organ — violates the principle of bodily autonomy.  Humanists believe bodily autonomy is very important, which is why humanists would oppose laws that prohibit abortion or force organ donation (or other forms of human life support).

Comment: If pregnancy is "terminated" in a way that produces a living baby, it's generally called an induced birth, not an abortion. I have seen it mentioned occasionally. Either way the baby will still die if it is not fed and kept warm and reasonably clean, which it will be unable to do for itself for some time.  As I understand it, humanists are generally against allowing a baby to starve to death, so I'm not convinced the life-support principle is the main factor here.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica "the baby will still die if it is not fed" - extending the analogy, Carmen's sister will still die if she's not cared for for some time, and Carmen will need to care for her for the next 2 decades of her recovery process, if she chooses to donate a kidney (or she's forced to donate one). This makes the pro-choice argument stronger, not weaker, in my opinion.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica Yes, parents have a duty to care for their baby, but this duty does not conflict with anybody's bodily autonomy, and they can outsource this if they want.  They can also give up the baby for adoption (I think?).  We can't currently outsource pregnancy after they started (surrogacy is also illegal in many countries, but that's a different discussion).  If we could transplant foetuses to other women or to machines with no major health detriment to the foetus/baby, the abortion discussion would get a new perspective, I think.

Comment: @PastychomperthanksMonica I don't know if induced early birth at request is legal when there is no medical reason.  "I no longer want to be pregnant, please induce the birth and take away the baby for adoption" as an alternative to an extremely late-term abortion — is that a thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't acknowledge that human fetuses are human, it's simpler.

Then you have sentient, suffering mother vs a cluster of cells.

So... just dehumanize fetuses, and you'll make it easier to abort them.

Comment: This is just a poor strawman. The most popular pro-choice arguments work even if you suppose that a fetus is equivalent to a fully-grown human and has a right to life. The argument just gets *stronger* if you consider the biological facts of what functions a fetus is capable of (facts don't care about your feelings).

Comment: Strawman? Where? I've seen a lot of folks on the left vote for equality. Equality means, every human has equal rights to live. Yet somehow, woman is always more important than fetus. However, when the child gets delivered, it's suddenly required for fathers to pay for the child.... despite that it was not required for the mother to deliver the very same child safely just a few months ago. So... seems like all children are equal, but only if mother wants them to live.

Comment: What is "human" (adjective) and why is it relevant?

Comment: Good answer, straight to the point. No judge would accept an excuse of a murderer, that the victim caused him extreme discomfort.

Comment: How does this answer the titular question? You have three one-sentence paragraphs written in the imperative mood; I don't see how that could ever be the answer to a “why?“ question.

Comment: @verybigcat Equality does not mean “every human has equal rights to live”. (I'm sure if you hold your _own_ political beliefs up to that standard, they will fall short.) See the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy article on equality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/equality/) for a brief introduction to the topic.

Comment: To expand on @user253751's comment, "human" as an adjective can be used either to mean personhood ("human being", the "human operator" of a computer system) or to indicate any association with *homo sapiens* and relatives ("human footprints", "human hair"). With terms like "human fetus" there is risk of accidental or deliberate confusion between the two meanings; it's uncontroversial to acknowledge that a "human fetus" is related to humans, but treating that as admission of fetal personhood is just cheap equivocation.

Comment: @Jacob3 This is both mischaracterising the facts (pregnancy isn't just about "extreme discomfort", it can be life-threatening, even with good medical care) and begging the question. By definition, "murder" is *illegal* killing; if the killer had an acceptable excuse they wouldn't be a "murderer" in the first place. But there are many circumstances in which "extreme discomfort" and/or risk to one's life *would* be accepted as justification for killing another human being, in which case the killer isn't a "murderer".

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent, No one is talking regarding cases where the mother's health is at severe stake. The risk of "healthy" women to die due to childbirth, in developed countries, is close to nonexistent.

Comment: @Jacob3 One of my friends, who would've been considered "healthy", nearly bled out giving birth (in a well-equipped hospital in a "developed" country). But she got off with long-lasting injuries and medical trauma. I'm sure it would be a great comfort to her to hear that her experience was "close to non-existent" though! 

Plus, in practice, anti-abortion measures very often *do* end up affecting cases where the mother's health is known to be at risk. No matter how much folk want to believe in the Shirley Exception.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent "murder means illegal killing" is completely irrelevant. It used to be legal to kill your slaves, but we still call it murder today.

Comment: @Jacob3 in some US states (don't remember which; might be just one) it is currently illegal to have an abortion to save your own life.

Comment: @user253751 And we call it "murder" today *because* it's now illegal.

Meanwhile, there are many circumstances in which it's still legal to do something that would lead to the death of a human being - especially in protection of one's own life, health, or liberty. These are not termed "murder", and a commonly-encountered position is that even if a fetus were considered a human being, abortion would be closer to these circumstances than the ones which we *do* acknowledge as "murder". 1/2

Comment: @user253751 Hence, an argument that boils down to "these factors don't excuse abortion b/c they wouldn't excuse murder" is just circular reasoning: "murder" effectively means "the forms of homicide we consider inexcusable". (Give or take murder/manslaughter distinctions, for which terminology varies.) In attempting to determine whether abortion should be legal, it skips over the entire question of "even if a fetus were considered human, should abortion be one of the forms of homicide that are legal?" and assumes that question has already been answered in the negative. 2/2

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent I would argue abortion is not even homicide. The facet of killing that makes it homocide is that the victim is a sapient being. Sapient non-humans count and non-sapient humans don't.

Comment: @user253751 do you think unconscious people count as sapient, or non-sapient? How about drug addicts?